# Why am I getting a parse error on the closing bracket in Haskell?

Tags: function, parsing, haskell, io, return

```
printExclamation :: Int -> IO()
pintExclamation n = do {
                        n <- getInt;
                        if n == n;
                        then return !
                      }
```

When compiling this, I get " **parse error on input `}'** " . I have no idea why.

Comment: There is no `else`. Furthermore there is no definition for `!` to return something, and you use both `n` as parameter and variable in the `do` block.

Comment: I know the if n == n does nothing, but want to see it compile first before I can work out what to do

Comment: in Haskell a `if ... then ... else ...` always has an `else` block, since `if ... then ... else ...` is *not* a statement, but an expression. In contrast to (most) imperative languages, this is just syntactical sugar for a function application, you can for example replace it with [**`ifThenElse`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.15/docs/Data-Bool-HT.html#v:ifThenElse).

Comment: where would I define to output many ! depending on n?

Comment: @Sattoshi7: since the type is `IO ()`, it means you can only return a unit `()`, not a value...

Comment: yes the unit I am trying to return are exclamation mark(s), specifically how many depending on the integer I decide to input.

Comment: return or print? `putStrLn "!"` has type `IO ()`, so that does not "inject" a value in the `IO` type, but in order to "return" it, you should change the type to `IO String`, and also return some string in the `else` case.

Answer (score 3):

The parser expects an `else` block. In Haskell it makes no sense to write `if … then …` without an `else …` block. An `if … then … else …` clause is not a statement, it is an expression. An expression that will use the value in the `then …` block in case the condition is `True`, and the part from the `else …` block otherwise.

You thus can write this as:

```
printExclamation :: Int -> IO()
printExclamation m = do
    n <- readLn
    if m == n
      then return ()
      else return ()
```

Beware that [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) injects a value in a monadic type. It is thus not equivalent to the `return` statement in (most) imperative languages that will "stop flow through the function".

You can for example print an exclamation mark in case the obtained number `n` is the same as `m` by using [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn):

```
printExclamation :: Int -> IO()
printExclamation m = do
    n <- readLn
    if m == n
      then putStrLn "!"
      else return ()
```

We then can test the function with:

```
Prelude> printExclamation 4
4
!
Prelude> printExclamation 3
4
Prelude>
```

Comment: I understand now. Thank you. Though when compiling it doesn't print ! There is just a blank line and upon hitting enter I get this message " *** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse) "

Comment: @Satoshi7: that's because you run the program likely when the stdin is already closed. `readLn` tries to read from the standard input channel.

Comment: I get this:  Prelude> printExclamation 4
4
!             , when I want to get !!!!  - the same number of ! as the integer I input

Comment: @Satoshi7: take a look at [**replicate**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate). If you however want to return something, and not read/print, you should not use an `IO` in the first place, but just a function `myfunc :: Int -> Int -> String`.